# Apply HTML tags removal to Pandas column

Tags: python, html, pandas

I need to remove the HTML tags from all in a pandas column and just keep the description.

I have already removed the tags for one column but need to apply them to others - this is what I had and did;

Input:

`df.description[1]`

Output:

```
'<p>Das Ziel der <a href="http://swa-muc.de">Software Architektur München Gruppe</a> ist es, Menschen, die sich mit Software-Architektur auseinandersetzen wollen, in und um München regelmäßig zusammenzubringen, und einen persönlichen Erfahrungsaustausch zu etablieren. Dazu dienen neben der Meetup-Gruppe insbesondere der persönliche Erfahrungsaustausch, organisiert in informellen Treffen, Diskussion von Erfahrungsberichten und Case Studies bis hin zu Vorträge und Workshops. Diese werden auch über Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/swamuc">@swamuc</a> und Meetup bekannt gegeben.</p>'
```

With I did;

```
read = df.description[1]
read_result = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', read)
print(read_result)
```

Output:

```
Das Ziel der Software Architektur München Gruppe ist es, Menschen, die sich mit Software-Architektur auseinandersetzen wollen, in und um München regelmäßig zusammenzubringen, und einen persönlichen Erfahrungsaustausch zu etablieren. Dazu dienen neben der Meetup-Gruppe insbesondere der persönliche Erfahrungsaustausch, organisiert in informellen Treffen, Diskussion von Erfahrungsberichten und Case Studies bis hin zu Vorträge und Workshops. Diese werden auch über Twitter @swamuc und Meetup bekannt gegeben.
```

This is all and well but I need to do this to the whole `df.description` Pandas column.

This is what I have tried:

```
 new_read = df.description[0:10148]
 new_read_result = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', new_read)
 print(new_read_result)
```

However, this is not functional and returns;

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

This is another method I'm trying for application:

```
df.description.apply(re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', new_read))
```

But isn't working either.

How can I apply it to the whole pandas column?

Answer (score 5):

Using `lambda` in `apply`:

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"description": ['<p>Hello</p>', '<p>World</p>']})
print( df.description.apply(lambda x: re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x)))
```

**Output:**

```
0    Hello
1    World
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Comment: This gives me the same output that you have up there but I want it to do that for the whole column not just for that one which is `df.description[1]`
Should I ignore `df = pd.Dataframe({"description...` because I have 10148 columns with descriptions

Comment: This should work for the whole column `df.description.apply(lambda x: re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x))`

Comment: I have used your example twice in the list as dummy data

Comment: Updated example.

Comment: It still isn't working, getting this error :
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: How do I compile ALL my descriptions into a list, like you've done with 'Hello, World'? 
This is how the first 5 descriptions look like: 
`0    <p><span><br><br>Who should join?&nbsp;</span>...
1    <p>Das Ziel der <a href="http://swa-muc.de">So...
2    <p><b>Who are we?</b> <br></p>\n<p>Brussels Le...
3    <p>Calling all analytical addicts, those of us...
4    <p>DUG was formed in 1998 to help a group of c...
Name: description, dtype: object`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171462/discussion-between-snow-fall-and-rakesh).

Comment: To use it as a list use `print(df.description.tolist())`

Comment: Sorry I cannot access chat from here

Comment: No problem - i was prompted to open a chat by Stackoverflow.

Comment: The output for the list is as follows: 

`IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.`

I don't think that's worked

Answer (score 1):

do the following

```
def parser(text):
    return re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(text))



result=df.description.apply(parser)
```

METHOD:2

```
df.description.apply(lambda x : re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(text)))
```

Comment: Getting an error: 

`TypeError: parser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'`

Comment: There is still an error, this time it is: 
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: can you show the code you are running. also the error traceback

Comment: `def parser(text):
    return re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)



result=df.description.apply(parser)` 


OUTPUT:

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: check the code now, i have edited it. i explicitly converted it into string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171464/discussion-between-kalyan-and-snow-fall).